# Could not load type from assembly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, types

for avoiding the duplicate codes, I wrote a method, which I pass a string(ClassNameString) as parameter into it, and use it to generate 2 things, one is the a url for WebClient, and one is a Class which name is the string value.

The 1st purpose can be done without a problem, but the 2nd really bothers me, I wrote the code below.

```
Type targetRawDataClassType = Type.GetType( ClassNameString, true );
```

but the codes falis, it said "Could not load type 'ClassNameString' from assembly 'ABCDEFG, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems very weird.

I solve the problem by refer the complete namespace when doing the GetType.
it seems that even I have refer the namespace using "using XXXXX" at first, it doesn't work. I should refer it in runtime.

this problem has been solved via the code below:

```
Type targetRawDataClassType = Type.GetType(
                               NameSpaceString + 
                               ClassNameString, 
                               true );
```

Comment: If your question has been answered (by your self), Mark it as answer.

Comment: Not sure how you are actually getting your namespace and class strings, but if you are getting them from Type in an earlier process, you can call Type.FullName which will return you the namespace and class in a single string.

Comment: @TyCobb The Type.FullName can only be refer when the Type declaration is completed. But my previous code fails to run, so I can't refer it by that. As the code above, I don't refer the NameSpaceString, I just type the actual namesapce as a string "xxxxxx" and join it with the ClassNameString, so I can fix the error.