# Could not load type 'ImageProcessor.Imaging.CropLayer' from assembly 'ImageProcessor'

Tags: c#, typeloadexception, imageprocessor

I'm working on a web-based image processing tool using cropper.js and ImageProcessor. I have an AJAX call that passes the cropper.js data to a C# handler, where that data is then passed to ImageProcessor and - in theory - used to crop the image and save it.

What's actually happening, when I run it locally through Visual Studio, is that the AJAX call returns a 500 exception and I see the following error message in the Diagnostics panel, under the "Events" tab:

> Could not load type 'ImageProcessor.Imaging.CropLayer' from assembly 'ImageProcessor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

ImageProcessor was installed correctly, via NuGet Package Manager, in both projects of my solution - the actual web application, and a class library named Middle that's referenced in the web app project. The handler is contained within Middle. The handler does **not** throw an exception if I remove all the code that references ImageProcessor.

I have no idea what could be causing this. I've tried Googling the issue and none of the answers I could find helped me. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16508981/3122701) suggests typing the complete namespaces, but I tried that and it didn't fix the issue. The comments on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58546514/3122701) suggest clearing out my bin and obj folders, cleaning and rebuilding the solution, but that didn't work either.

Here's what my C# handler looks like so far (I can't finish it until I know whether what I have so far works, but I can't test it properly due to the issue I'm having).

```cs
using ImageProcessor;
using ImageProcessor.Imaging;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

namespace Middle
{
    public class CropImage : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var x = float.Parse(context.Request["x"]);
            var y = float.Parse(context.Request["y"]);
            var width = float.Parse(context.Request["width"]);
            var height = float.Parse(context.Request["height"]);
            var cropLayer = new CropLayer(x, y, width, height);

            var filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + context.Request["fileName"];
            var imageData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
            {
                using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    // Initialize the ImageFactory using the overload to preserve EXIF metadata.
                    using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: true))
                    {
                        // Load, resize, set the format and quality and save an image.
                        imageFactory.Load(inStream)
                                    .Crop(cropLayer)
                                    .Save(outStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there's any other information you need, please do let me know.

**How can I resolve this issue?**

Comment: The users may not have the credentials to run application.  Did you set application to RUN AS ADMIN?  Users have GUEST Accounts on the server and have very limited access to the server resources.  Error 500 is a general exception indicating the server had an error.

Comment: I'm testing this in Visual Studio via localhost, it's not a server error. Edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Are you an Admin?  VS doesn't automatically start with ADMIN credentials.  You need to create a shortcut to VS.  Then start by right click shortcut and select run as admin.  Try from cmd.exe >Ping Localhost to see what is returned.  On server end, it is better to use IPAddress.Any than to use localhost.  The client may be using local host and then you will get a conflict if both client and server are using localhost.

Comment: @jdweng This can't be a Visual Studio issue. The handler worked perfectly fine before I added the ImageProcessor code, then I added the ImageProcessor code and now it's throwing the 500 exception.

Comment: So you are saying it is not the connection (localhost).  Then it is something with the NuGet.  You need to test the NuGet by itself in VS without the connection.  You probably combined two projects together and there is something that conflicts in the libraries.  Make sure the two projects are targeting the same version of Net and you rebuild both.  Also in 2nd project make sure the executable (debug or release) is the latest.

Comment: Why not use ImageProcessor.Web? https://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/

Comment: I almost forgot about this question. I ended up taking a completely different approach that didn't use ImageProcessor, so I'm not sure what to do with this question. Do I delete it?

Comment: The question should remain. It looks like a versioning issue to me where you are referencing a version that does not match the dll you have.